Pushing Docker image to GCP Container Registry times out despite successful auth
I am unable to push built Docker images to GCP Artifact Registry, despite GCP SDK & auth being configured successfully.
This is my GithubActions pipeline setup:
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}

      - name: Set up GCP SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}

      - name: Configure Docker to use GCP
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker $CONTAINER_REGISTRY

      - name: Build and Push Docker image
        env:
          SHA_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
          ENV_TAG: dev
        run: |
          docker build -t $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:$SHA_TAG -t $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:$ENV_TAG -t $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:latest .
          docker push $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:$SHA_TAG
          docker push $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:$ENV_TAG
          docker push $CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$SERVICE_NAME:latest

As you can see in the screenshots below, all the steps conclude successfully, except the "push" part of the "Build and Push docker image" step:


Not really sure what's the issue here.

Are you sure that the variable $SERVICE_NAME contains the full path, including the project and repository name? See https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot#pull for an example. It's also weird that you run that configure-docker command without the --quiet flag since it looks like it's interactive.

@somethingsomething, you were right. Seems like I wasn't adding both the project_id and the repo name.
Also, I added the --quiet flag. Thank you.
You can add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

You are not using a valid image path to push to, the path has to be of the form
$CONTAINER_REGISTRY/$PROJECT/$REPO/$SERVICE_NAME:$TAG

You can find this information here and here
